# Is there a way to silently say yes to untracked file in arc patch?

Tags: git, phabricator, git-untracked

When I `arc patch` I will get

> You have untracked files in this working copy 
>   Ignore these untracked files and continue (Y/n)

I dont want to delete the untracked files or put them into .gitignore. I just want to silently say yes. Is there a way to achieve it, e.g., command arg?

Comment: That particular message is not coming from Git, as `git push` does not look at your work-tree at all. My guess is that it is coming from a pre-push hook that you installed. If so, inspect and modify your pre-push hook, or remove it, or disable it with `git push --no-verify`.

Comment: Downvoted because the question is misleading: as @torek said git doesn't output this message, and all answers are about git fixes.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to add it to `.git/info/exclude`, which works like a repo-local version of `.gitignore`. Any entry added to `.git/info/exclude` will behave identical to those in `.gitignore` file in the repository, but `.git/info/exclude` will not affect your working tree and changes to it don't need to be committed.